# Is it normal that Matlab nntool with defaults parameters outperform tensorflow adam, adadelta with default parameters?

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

I'm working on a regression problem and I tried it via tensorflow and keras with various Neural Network optimizers such as SGD, Adam and Adadelta and also matlab nntool with its default parameters tainlm " Levenberg-Marquardt optimization " and adaptation learning function "learngdm" gradient descent with momentum. Matlab outperforms tensorflow by large distance, such that matlab performance reach less than 1 mse while tensorflow stuck at 3815 mse. Is that logic or I'm doing something wrong ? Is there is certain parameters should I tune to duplicate the matlab performance via tensorflow ?

Comment: You get what you pay for, I guess...

Comment: But how come, there is numerous research paper have been recently published on these optimizers how Levenberg-Marquardt "Old" still outperform them ?!